# Is it possible to modify mobx variables or react readux outside the application?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-redux, mobx

I want to use a store to save data and not be calling to firebase to ask for an id all the time to save it in Mobx or react redux and pass to my other components (I don't know which are secure or not), but I would like to know if it is safe to save an id which I use to identify the movements of a user and that for example another user does not introduce values ​​to my web application to see the values ​​of his user or can see the id.

In firebase exists a user token, but I use my own id to query data for other functions.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I see that save important data in the client side is not a good option but i will working with firebase and firebase had the  auth api and i can use custom claims that allow save custom data like if your are admin, tokens and other fields.

I will use mobx for save state but the important data, i will save as custom claims.